# PHP mail() issue

Tags: php

I have a php page that includes an inquiry form that refers to itself as the form action.

Once completed the form writes to a database within a try-catch construct.  I want to send an email to the administrator to say that someone has added themselves to the database.

All of the code works until:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f' . $from))
{ #And finally send them a thanks
   header('Location: thanks.html.php');
   exit();
} else {
   echo 'Email did not send';
   exit();
}
```

The code above this block all works because I get a write into the database, and the 'if' test passes because the redirect to the thanks page also works! What have I missed?

Comment: So the email is not being sent to the admin?

Comment: `'-f ' . $from` you need that extra space in there.

Comment: Can someone explain the extra space?

Comment: I'm not user2938456 btw... lol.. just curious as to why the extra space is needed myself. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi  I forgot to add that before I embedded the code onto the main page, I tested it with just a self referring page that collected the email address, posted and returned to the thanks page...that worked!  My database write is using PDO Objects and finishes with an execute instruction.  I know that writes, and I know the code logic continues because the only way to get the thanks page is with a successful send...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to make use of **`additional parameters`**.

Exerpt from PHP Manual

> The additional_parameters parameter can be used to pass an additional
>   parameter to the program configured to use when sending mail using the
>   sendmail_path.

```
<?php
mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null, '-fwebmaster@example.com');
?>
```

### Route : 2

Try something like this.

Your **`$from`** is contained in the **`$headers`** variable itself , so you don't have to specify.

```
 <?php
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

   if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    { #And finally send them a thanks
   header('Location: thanks.html.php');
   exit();
   } else {
   echo 'Email did not send';
   exit();
   }   
   ?>
```

Comment: Yes I am using the additional parameter -f .  It's obligatory on my host site.

Answer (score 0):

AT last...The answer.  Nothing wrong with the code!  I was falling over the web hosts anti spam filter in mail.  Because I was testing the script with my own email address, it refused to send the mail assuming it was spam!  As soon as I put in a completely new email address it sent the email!

Thanks to everyone that offered help!